# performance query issue - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, oracle11g

I have two views, `v_movimiento_no_duplicado` and `v_personas_no_duplicadas`. Both queries removes duplicates from tables `CLM020A` and `CLM010A` respectively. When i execute each query individually i get fast return, when i join them is fast too. Problem is when i put some predicates, for example:

```
SELECT *
  FROM v_movimiento_no_duplicado
       INNER JOIN v_personas_no_duplicadas USING (cedula_rel)
 WHERE     LENGTH (nombres_010) <= 30
       AND LENGTH (apellidos_010) <= 30
       --AND LENGTH (cedula_rel) <= 15;
```

Without last predicate takes 125 ms(is ok),but if add third predicate takes 11 seconds. I haven't indexes at this moment, but i have tried indexes for each of three colums, composites indexes even function-based indexes, but result is the same or worst. This are the plans for both cases:

With two predicates (faster):

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |          |    27 |  7371 |   253   (2)| 00:00:04 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN               |          |    27 |  7371 |   253   (2)| 00:00:04 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN              |          |    27 |  7047 |   149   (3)| 00:00:02 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN SEMI        |          |    14 |  1596 |    46   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     JOIN FILTER CREATE   | :BF0000  |    14 |  1148 |    22   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL   | CLM010A  |    14 |  1148 |    22   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |     VIEW                 | VW_NSO_1 |    56 |  1792 |    23   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |      FILTER              |          |       |       |            |          |
|   8 |       HASH GROUP BY      |          |     1 |   672 |    23   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |        JOIN FILTER USE   | :BF0000  |  5532 | 66384 |    22   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL| CLM010A  |  5532 | 66384 |    22   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL     | CLM020A  | 10734 |  1540K|   102   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|  12 |   VIEW                   | VW_NSO_2 | 10734 |   125K|   104   (2)| 00:00:02 |
|  13 |    HASH GROUP BY         |          | 10734 |   461K|   104   (2)| 00:00:02 |
|* 14 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL    | CLM020A  | 10734 |   461K|   102   (0)| 00:00:02 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("M".ROWID="FILA")
   2 - access("CEDULA_REL"="CEDULA_REL")
   3 - access("CEDULA_REL"="CEDULA_REL")
   5 - filter(LENGTH("NOMBRES_010")<=30 AND LENGTH("APELLIDOS_010")<=30)
   7 - filter(COUNT("CEDULA_REL")=1)
  10 - filter(SYS_OP_BLOOM_FILTER(:BF0000,"CEDULA_REL"))
  14 - filter(("M"."TIPO_020"='E' OR "M"."TIPO_020"='S') AND 
              "M"."LUGARMOV_020" IS NOT NULL)
```

Now, with three predicates (slower):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |         |     1 |   229 |   252   (2)| 00:00:04 |
|*  1 |  FILTER              |         |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN          |         |     1 |   229 |   125   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | CLM010A |     1 |    82 |    22   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | CLM020A | 10734 |  1540K|   102   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|*  5 |   FILTER             |         |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |    HASH GROUP BY     |         |     1 |    12 |    23   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| CLM010A |  5532 | 66384 |    22   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |   FILTER             |         |       |       |            |          |
|   9 |    HASH GROUP BY     |         |   108 |  4752 |   104   (2)| 00:00:02 |
|* 10 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| CLM020A | 10734 |   461K|   102   (0)| 00:00:02 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter( EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "LIMOV"."CLM010A" "P2" GROUP BY 
              "CEDULA_REL" HAVING "CEDULA_REL"=:B1 AND COUNT("CEDULA_REL")=1) AND  
              EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "LIMOV"."CLM020A" "M" WHERE ("M"."TIPO_020"='E' 
              OR "M"."TIPO_020"='S') AND "M"."LUGARMOV_020" IS NOT NULL GROUP BY 
              UPPER(TRIM("M"."LUGARMOV_020"))||UPPER("M"."TIPO_020")||TO_CHAR(INTERNAL
              _FUNCTION("M"."FECHA_020"),'YYYYMMDDHH24MI')||"M"."CEDULA_REL" HAVING 
              MAX("M".ROWID)=:B2))
   2 - access("CEDULA_REL"="CEDULA_REL")
   3 - filter(LENGTH("NOMBRES_010")<=30 AND LENGTH("APELLIDOS_010")<=30 
              AND LENGTH("CEDULA_REL")<=15)
   5 - filter("CEDULA_REL"=:B1 AND COUNT("CEDULA_REL")=1)
   8 - filter(MAX("M".ROWID)=:B1)
  10 - filter(("M"."TIPO_020"='E' OR "M"."TIPO_020"='S') AND 
              "M"."LUGARMOV_020" IS NOT NULL)
```

As you can see both plans are differents. I haven't much experience working with plans, any help will be appreciated.

--VIEWS

```
   CREATE VIEW V_MOVIMIENTO_NO_DUPLICADO SELECT "CEDULA_REL",
          "TIPO_020",
          "FECHA_020",
          "LUGARMOV_020",
          "CLM_020",
          "TRASLADO_020",
          "RESPALDADO",
          "ESTADIA",
          "DIRECCION",
          "FECHA_LETRA",
          "HORA_SERVER",
          "USUARIO"
     FROM movimiento m
    WHERE m.ROWID IN (  SELECT MAX (m.ROWID) fila
                          FROM movimiento m
                         WHERE     M.lugarmov_020 IS NOT NULL
                               AND M.tipo_020 IN ('E', 'S')
                      GROUP BY    UPPER (TRIM (M.lugarmov_020))
                               || UPPER (M.tipo_020)
                               || TO_CHAR (M.fecha_020, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI')
                               || M.CEDULA_REL)

CREATE VIEW V_PERSONAS_NO_DUPLICADAS SELECT CEDULA_REL,
          NOMBRES_010,
          APELLIDOS_010,
          FECHANAC_010,
          NACIONALIDAD_010,
          TVIAJERO_010,
          RESPALDADO,
          RESIDENCIA,
          SEXO,
          FREGISTRO,
          PC,
          USUARIO,
          USERUPDATE,
          DATEUPDATE
     FROM persona P1
    WHERE cedula_rel IN (  SELECT cedula_rel
                             FROM persona P2
                         GROUP BY cedula_rel
                           HAVING COUNT (cedula_rel) = 1)
```

--Plans after indexes were added:

**Fastest Query:** (taking 12 secs more)

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                      | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                  |     1 |   261 |   133   (4)| 00:00:02 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                  |                  |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                 |                  |     1 |   261 |    29   (7)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                |                  |     1 |   114 |    26   (8)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     VIEW                       | VW_NSO_1         |    56 |  1792 |    23   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      FILTER                    |                  |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |       HASH GROUP BY            |                  |     1 |   672 |    23   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |        TABLE ACCESS FULL       | CLM010A          |  5532 | 66384 |    22   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CLM010A          |     1 |    82 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IDX_CEDULA_REL   |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN            | IDX_CEDULA_REL_2 |     2 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 11 |     FILTER                     |                  |       |       |            |          |
|  12 |      HASH GROUP BY             |                  |   108 |  4752 |   104   (2)| 00:00:02 |
|* 13 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL        | CLM020A          | 10734 |   461K|   102   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|  14 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | CLM020A          |     1 |   147 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - filter(COUNT("CEDULA_REL")=1)
   8 - filter(LENGTH("NOMBRES_010")<=30)
   9 - access("CEDULA_REL"="CEDULA_REL")
       filter(LENGTH("CEDULA_REL")<=15)
  10 - access("CEDULA_REL"="CEDULA_REL")
       filter( EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "LIMOV"."CLM020A" "M" WHERE ("M"."TIPO_020"='E' OR 
              "M"."TIPO_020"='S') AND "M"."LUGARMOV_020" IS NOT NULL GROUP BY 
              UPPER(TRIM("M"."LUGARMOV_020"))||UPPER("M"."TIPO_020")||TO_CHAR(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("M"."FECH
              A_020"),'YYYYMMDDHH24MI')||"M"."CEDULA_REL" HAVING MAX("M".ROWID)=:B1))
  11 - filter(MAX("M".ROWID)=:B1)
  13 - filter(("M"."TIPO_020"='E' OR "M"."TIPO_020"='S') AND "M"."LUGARMOV_020" IS NOT 
              NULL)
```

**Slowest Query:**(canceled at 2 mins)

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                        | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                 |                  |     1 |   241 |   116   (3)| 00:00:02 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                          |                  |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   HASH GROUP BY                  |                  |     1 |   241 |   116   (3)| 00:00:02 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                  |                  |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                 |                  |     1 |   241 |    11   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                |                  |     1 |    94 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CLM010A          |     1 |    82 |     7   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN          | IDX_CEDULA_LEN   |    50 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN           | IDX_CEDULA_REL   |     1 |    12 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN            | IDX_CEDULA_REL_2 |     2 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |       FILTER                     |                  |       |       |            |          |
|  11 |        HASH GROUP BY             |                  |   108 |  4752 |   104   (2)| 00:00:02 |
|* 12 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL        | CLM020A          | 10734 |   461K|   102   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|  13 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | CLM020A          |     1 |   147 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(COUNT("CEDULA_REL")=1)
   6 - filter(LENGTH("NOMBRES_010")<=30 AND LENGTH("APELLIDOS_010")<=30)
   7 - access(LENGTH("CEDULA_REL")<=15)
   8 - access("CEDULA_REL"="CEDULA_REL")
   9 - access("CEDULA_REL"="CEDULA_REL")
       filter( EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "LIMOV"."CLM020A" "M" WHERE ("M"."TIPO_020"='E' OR 
              "M"."TIPO_020"='S') AND "M"."LUGARMOV_020" IS NOT NULL GROUP BY 
              UPPER(TRIM("M"."LUGARMOV_020"))||UPPER("M"."TIPO_020")||TO_CHAR(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("M"."FECHA_
              020"),'YYYYMMDDHH24MI')||"M"."CEDULA_REL" HAVING MAX("M".ROWID)=:B1))
  10 - filter(MAX("M".ROWID)=:B1)
  12 - filter(("M"."TIPO_020"='E' OR "M"."TIPO_020"='S') AND "M"."LUGARMOV_020" IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: How many rows are in the result with and without the last predicate? And how many rows in the 2 base tables? (This is to first ensure the statistics are current). When you say it's fast when you run them individually and even join them, is it the IDE just showing you the first n rows quickly or did you fetch all rows and calculate the time after that?

Comment: There are always 10716 rows for both cases, CLM010A(5532), CLM020A(10734). I'm using toad, it always show the first 500 rows, but i think the problem is in the optimizer plan selection, note that both plans differs between them, and i only add one predicate.

Comment: In the second plan, the optimizer thinks that 1 row is being returned and in the first plan 27. I would first gather stats on this table and all dependent indexes just to be sure. If that doesn't work, you should share the table structure with indexes on which columns.

Comment: I gather stats for both table and nothing changed, i post the views code, `movimiento` and `persona` are synonyms of tables `CLM020A` and `CLM010A` respectively. I haven'n any index.

Comment: Do you have any function-based indexes created that match the LENGTH calls on the constraints?

Comment: @OldProgrammer In this moment i haven't, but i tried create one for each `LENGTH (nombres_010)`, `LENGTH (apellidos_010)` and `LENGTH (cedula_rel) <= 15` and doesn't works

Comment: Seems your views are itself SELECTs on views. Go through all the filter predicates and access predicates. Those are the final steps taken by oracle on the base tables CLM020A and CLM010A. Without knowing what the other views look like it would be hard to say why oracle tried a different approach in the two queries. Try to see if you can convert any full scans on the filter predicates by adding indexes if it is indeed a 'selective' filter. Especially step 3* in the second plan could use a composite index on the 3 length fields.

Comment: What doesn't work - the Create index statement, or after you create them, they are not used?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yes, they are being used, and the plan is even better, but the time is getting worst, i really don't understand :(

Comment: @ruudvan I try to put an index in column `cedula_rel` and three function-based indexes in columns (`cedula_rel`,`nombres_010`,`apellidos_010`), the full access disappear, the cost was reduced, but time  was increased instead of going down.

Comment: try setting up autotrace and look at the tkprof output.

Comment: Have you tried using optimizer hints (docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/hintsref.htm) to experiment with different plans?

Comment: Try to create an index on `movimiento( TIPO_020, LUGARMOV_020)` for this predicate: ` 12 - filter(("M"."TIPO_020"='E' OR "M"."TIPO_020"='S') AND "M"."LUGARMOV_020" IS NOT NULL)`, the cost of checking this predicate is the highest in the plan, oracle will do a full scan of this index instead of the full table scan.

Comment: @kordirko Looks like was a problem of the order of views, i have never seen this before. Thanks to all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem changing the order of the views in the join, then the execution plan changes, and filters changes drastically.

**Slowest query:**

```
SELECT *
  FROM v_movimiento_no_duplicado
       INNER JOIN v_personas_no_duplicadas USING (cedula_rel)
 WHERE     LENGTH (nombres_010) <= 30
       AND LENGTH (apellidos_010) <= 30
       AND LENGTH (cedula_rel) <= 15;

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |         |     1 |   229 |   252   (2)| 00:00:04 |
|*  1 |  FILTER              |         |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN          |         |     1 |   229 |   125   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | CLM010A |     1 |    82 |    22   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | CLM020A | 10734 |  1540K|   102   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|*  5 |   FILTER             |         |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |    HASH GROUP BY     |         |     1 |    12 |    23   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| CLM010A |  5532 | 66384 |    22   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |   FILTER             |         |       |       |            |          |
|   9 |    HASH GROUP BY     |         |   108 |  4752 |   104   (2)| 00:00:02 |
|* 10 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| CLM020A | 10734 |   461K|   102   (0)| 00:00:02 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

1 - filter( EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "LIMOV"."CLM010A" "P2" GROUP BY
"CEDULA_REL" HAVING "CEDULA_REL"=:B1 AND COUNT("CEDULA_REL")=1) AND
EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM "LIMOV"."CLM020A" "M" WHERE ("M"."TIPO_020"='E'
OR "M"."TIPO_020"='S') AND "M"."LUGARMOV_020" IS NOT NULL GROUP BY
UPPER(TRIM("M"."LUGARMOV_020"))||UPPER("M"."TIPO_020")||TO_CHAR(INTERNAL
_FUNCTION("M"."FECHA_020"),'YYYYMMDDHH24MI')||"M"."CEDULA_REL" HAVING
MAX("M".ROWID)=:B2))
2 - access("CEDULA_REL"="CEDULA_REL")
3 - filter(LENGTH("NOMBRES_010")<=30 AND LENGTH("APELLIDOS_010")<=30
AND LENGTH("CEDULA_REL")<=15)
5 - filter("CEDULA_REL"=:B1 AND COUNT("CEDULA_REL")=1)
8 - filter(MAX("M".ROWID)=:B1)
10 - filter(("M"."TIPO_020"='E' OR "M"."TIPO_020"='S') AND
"M"."LUGARMOV_020" IS NOT NULL)
```

Check that filter 1 looks to be a bit expensive. When i changed the order of views it just disappear.

```
SELECT *
  FROM v_personas_no_duplicadas
       INNER JOIN v_movimiento_no_duplicado USING (cedula_rel)
 WHERE    LENGTH (nombres_010) <= 30
       AND LENGTH (apellidos_010) <= 30
       AND LENGTH (cedula_rel) <= 15;

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |          |    14 |  3822 |   253   (2)| 00:00:04 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN SEMI       |          |    14 |  3822 |   253   (2)| 00:00:04 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN           |          |    14 |  3374 |   229   (2)| 00:00:03 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN          |          |    14 |  3206 |   125   (1)| 00:00:02 |
|*  4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL | CLM010A  |    14 |  1148 |    22   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL | CLM020A  |   537 | 78939 |   102   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|   6 |    VIEW               | VW_NSO_1 | 10734 |   125K|   104   (2)| 00:00:02 |
|   7 |     HASH GROUP BY     |          | 10734 |   461K|   104   (2)| 00:00:02 |
|*  8 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| CLM020A  | 10734 |   461K|   102   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|   9 |   VIEW                | VW_NSO_2 |    56 |  1792 |    23   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|* 10 |    FILTER             |          |       |       |            |          |
|  11 |     HASH GROUP BY     |          |     1 |   672 |    23   (5)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL| CLM010A  |  5532 | 66384 |    22   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

1 - access("CEDULA_REL"="CEDULA_REL")
2 - access("M".ROWID="FILA")
3 - access("CEDULA_REL"="CEDULA_REL")
4 - filter(LENGTH("NOMBRES_010")<=30 AND LENGTH("APELLIDOS_010")<=30)
5 - filter(LENGTH("CEDULA_REL")<=15)
8 - filter(("M"."TIPO_020"='E' OR "M"."TIPO_020"='S') AND
"M"."LUGARMOV_020" IS NOT NULL)
10 - filter(COUNT("CEDULA_REL")=1)
```